# How does this git alias work?

Tags: bash, git

Usually, git aliases are confined to a single command:

```
git config --global alias.ci commit
```

So, instead of `git commit` you could do `git ci`

But it seems you can insert a function in there as well:

```
git config --global alias.up-sub '!f() { cd $1 && git checkout master && git pull && git submodule update --init --recursive; }; f'
```

This allows you to call `git up-sub some-submodule`

The question is: how does it work? I haven't seen the `!f()` syntax in any other context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like a regular shell function definition and invocation. Only the bang stands out, but a quick search through the `git-config(1)` manual shows an explanation:

> If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell command. For example, defining "alias.new = !gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD", the invocation "git new" is equivalent to running the shell command "gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD". Note that shell commands will be executed from the top-level directory of a repository, which may not necessarily be the current directory.

Without the bang, it would alias a `git` subcommand.

Comment: Talk about RTFM; I though it was something native to bash. Thanks! :)