# How to create an alias for two Git commands that use a parameter?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, git, alias

I regularly have to delete a local and remote [Git](https://git-scm.com) branch. Therefore, I run the following commands:

```
$ git branch -d feature-branch
$ git push --delete origin feature-branch
```

Since I mostly execute these two commands in a row, I would like to create an alias for them. Here is my approach:

```
alias gpdo='git branch -d $1 && git push --delete origin $1
```

However, this fails with the following error:

> fatal: branch name required

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you want aliases to have parameters you can use functions, e.g.

```
$ gpdo () {
    git branch -d "$1" && git push --delete origin "$1"
}
```

Then you can do `gpdo branch_name`

This is also useful for multiple commands although they can also be done with an alias with multiple `&&`s **if** there are no parameters and no conditional logic, looping, etc. however when parameters are needed I switch to using functions

Git itself also allows aliases, for example see:

- [How does this git alias work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47275/10043)
- [How can I create an alias for a git [action] command (which includes spaces)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48862/10043)

You may also find [Git alias multi-commands with ; and &&](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/198425/10043) helpful

Comment: I tested your function. Only the second command is executed.

Comment: Sorry again - but the solution does not work for me.

Comment: @JJD: This solution is clearly correct, given the question. You will need to provide a better diagnosis than "doesn't work" if you want help. For instance, are you certain that your supplied commands are correct? I have corrected the minor discrepancies between your question and this answer; you might want to retry the solution as I've edited it.

Comment: @JJD, shooting in the dark here: If the branch you are trying to delete is currently checked out, git won't let you delete it.  (But even then there is no way that the shell can execute only the *right side* of a dual command connected with `&&`.  You are simply mistaken.)

Comment: @WarrenYoung Finally, you nudged my nose into the dirt again. I had an **alias** configured somewhere else which **overwrote** the function. In short, the function by Michael works - thanks! One issue (worth a new question) is that there is no auto-completion for branch names when I use the function within zsh.