# zsh: Tab completion for function with Git commands

Tags: zsh, git, autocomplete, function

In zsh I am using the following [function to delete a local and a remote branch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248080/how-to-create-an-alias-for-two-git-commands-that-use-a-parameter) with one command:

```bash
gpDo () {
    git branch -d "$1" && git push --delete origin "$1"
}
```

Currently, auto-completion for the Git branch does not work. I have to manually type the whole branch name. How can I get tab completion working for such as function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're using the [“new” completion system](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-System) enabled by `compinit`. If you're using oh-my-zsh, you are.

You need to tell zsh to use git branch names for `gpDo`. Git already comes with a way to complete branch names. As of zsh 5.0.7 this is the function `__git_branch_names` but this isn't a stable interface so it could change in other versions. To use this function, put this line in your `.zshrc`:

```
compdef __git_branch_names gpDo
```

With this declaration, completion after `gpDo` will only work after you've completed something on a `git` command line at least once. This is due to a quirk of function autoloading in zsh. Alternatively, run `_git 2>/dev/null` in your `.zshrc`; this causes an error because the completion function is called in an invalid context, but the error is harmless, and the side effect of loading `_git` and associated functions including __git_branch_names` remains.

Alternatively, define your own function for git branch completion. Quick-and-dirty way:

```
_JJD_git_branch_names () {
  compadd "${(@)${(f)$(git branch -a)}#??}"
}
```

Comment: I tried your first approach with having zsh 5.1.1 installed. It fails with the error `gpDo (eval):1: command not found: __git_branch_names`. Please note that I am also using *oh-my-zsh* if this allows for another solution.

Comment: @JJD Had you already performed a completion with git? That loads the function. Alternatively you can run `_git` once, which loads and executes the function (there's no way to load an autoloaded function without executing it, unfortunately).