# Zsh autocompletion for function based on git, why is compdef not working in .zshrc?

Tags: zsh, git, autocomplete

I have an alias for `git` defined as

```
alias g=git
```

With this and my zsh and [antigen](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen) setup, `g` has the same auto-completion as `git`.

However, when I replace `g` with a function to show the git status by default

```
g() {
  if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    git status --short --branch
  else
    git "$@"
  fi
}
```

this, naturally, doesn't work anymore. The same goes for a `git-all` function to run the same git command in all repositories in sub-directories

```
git-all() { 
  if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    find . -maxdepth 3 -type d -name .git -execdir echo \; -execdir pwd \; -execdir git status --short --branch \;
  else
    find . -maxdepth 3 -type d -name .git -execdir echo \; -execdir pwd \; -execdir git "$@" \;
  fi
}
alias ga='git-all'
```

I would like to have completion for all these, `g`, `git-all`, and `ga`, just like for `git`.

The [docs](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org#copying-completions-from-another-command) say

> If you want a command, say cmd1, to have the same completions as another, say cmd2, which has already had completions defined for it, you can do this:
>
> ```
> compdef cmd1=cmd2
> ```

So, I type

```
compdef git-all=git
```

in my current `zsh` session, and it works! Nice.

So, I put the compdefs in my `.zshrc` after my antigen setup, which has `zsh-users/zsh-completions` to init the completions, and after my alias and function definitions

```
if [ -f ~/.antigenrc ]; then
  source ~/.antigenrc
fi

if [ -f ~/.sh_aliases ]; then
  source ~/.sh_aliases
fi

compdef g=git
compdef ga=git
compdef git-all=git

antigen apply
```

And my antigenrc looks like this:

```
source /usr/share/zsh-antigen/antigen.zsh

antigen use oh-my-zsh

antigen bundle gradle/gradle-completion
antigen bundle command-not-found
antigen bundle MikeDacre/cdbk
antigen bundle zsh-users/zsh-completions
antigen bundle zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting

antigen theme ys
```

and I start a new zsh shell. Now the completions don't work.

How can that be? An interactive zsh shell reads the .zshrc (if I put an `echo` in there, I see the output). If I put the compdef before the antigen setup, I get errors about compdef not being defined, but when they are at the end they don't show errors, they just don't work. Maybe antigen is doing something strange, but even then, the completions are defined after the antigen setup, so antigen shouldn't mess them up?

I also tried adding `_git 2>/dev/null` to my .zshrc as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269791/zsh-tab-completion-for-function-with-git-commands), or using `compdef '_dispatch git git' g` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221239/zsh-use-completions-for-command-x-when-i-type-command-y/4221640#4221640), to no avail.

My zsh version is 5.8.

Comment: Please post your complete `.zshrc` so that people can reproduce your setup. Also tell us what zsh version you're using in case it matters. What's the output of `echo $_comps[git] $_comps[ga] $_comps[g] $_comps[git-all]`? Run `set -x` then type `g` <space> <tab>; what's the output (it might be very long)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My complete .zshrc is very long, I understand that somewhere in there might be the source of the problem, but I'm pretty sure I posted the relevant parts. It's probably something to do with antigen. I'll add my antigenrc. `echo $_comps[git] $_comps[ga] $_comps[g] $_comps[git-all]` return just `_git` once.

Comment: I'm onto something now: When I type `type compdef` in my zsh, it says `compdef is a shell function from /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/compinit`, whereas when I include it in my `.zshrc` it prints `compdef is a shell function from /home/dario/.antigen/init.zsh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. It seems to be a bug with antigen. There is also an [issue](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen/issues/701) on the antigen Github, which contains a workaround:

> For me the way of fixing it was to comment out in the .antigen/init.zsh the following lines:
>
> ```
> # autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook; add-zsh-hook precmd _antigen_compinit
> # compdef () {}
> ```
>
> I know it's not the proper way of fixing it and that it can cause some other errors, but I'm heavily using kubectl so I need autocompletion so much

The function `compdef () {}` obviously doesn't do anything and is what is called in my `.zshrc`. The quoted workaround didn't work for me, because the `.antigen/init.zsh` is (re-)generated by antigen, but what works for me is to put `autoload -U +X compinit && compinit` before my `compdef`s in my `.zshrc`:

```
#type compdef #uncomment this to see the problem
autoload -U +X compinit && compinit
#type compdef #uncomment this to see the solution
compdef g=git
compdef ga=git
compdef git-all=git
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the [Github Issue Comment](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen/issues/701#issuecomment-1019046492), a workaround (unknown consequences) you would need to comment the following line in `antigen.zsh` not `.antigen/init.zsh` (since `init.zsh` is generated every time antigen loads)

```
# autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook; add-zsh-hook precmd _antigen_compinit
# compdef () {}
```